# Firefox bookmarks exploration not going past first level with Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, firefox-addon, bookmarks

I've written some code to explore my Firefox bookmarks but I only get the first level of bookmarks (i.e. I don't get the links in the folders).

e.g.

- Search_engines /

  - yahoo.com
- google.com

In this example I have only access to Search_engines and google.com not yahoo.com

My function being recursive I don't know why this happens.

my code :

```
function browse_bookmark_node(bookmark_node, array)
{
    // We explore the bookmarks with this function     
   // iterate over the immediate children of this folder
   for (var i = 0; i < bookmark_node.childCount; i ++) {
       var node = bookmark_node.getChild(i);
       if (node.type ==0) {
          // the node is a link so we add it to the array
          array.push(node.title); 
       } else if (node.type ==6) {
          // the node is a folder so we explore it
          browse_bookmark_node(node, array);
       }
   }
}

function wrapper_browse_bookmark_node(bookmark_node) {
   // We use this function to wrapp the function browse_bookmark_node and keep track of the links
   var array = [];
   browse_bookmark_node(bookmark_node, array);
   return array;
}

// All the code following is used to access firefox bookmarks and works fine
var historyService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/browser/nav-history-service;1"]
                               .getService(Components.interfaces.nsINavHistoryService);
var options = historyService.getNewQueryOptions();
var query = historyService.getNewQuery();

var bookmarksService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/browser/nav-bookmarks-service;1"]
                                 .getService(Components.interfaces.nsINavBookmarksService);
var bookmarksMenuFolder = bookmarksService.bookmarksMenuFolder;

query.setFolders([bookmarksMenuFolder], 1);

var result = historyService.executeQuery(query, options);
var rootNode = result.root;
rootNode.containerOpen = true;

// The function call to explore the bookmarks
var links_array = wrapper_browse_bookmark_node(rootNode);

// close a container after using it!
rootNode.containerOpen = false;
```

Comment: @Wladimir Palant Thanks a lot for your answer. After reading my code I realized there was a typo in it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One obvious mistake is using `toolbarFolder` as a starting point - that's only the bookmarks toolbar. If you want all bookmarks (meaning bookmarks menu, bookmarks toolbar and unsorted bookmarks) you need to change query parameters:

```
query.setFolders([
    bookmarksService.bookmarksMenuFolder,
    bookmarksService.toolbarFolder,
    bookmarksService.unfiledBookmarksFolder
], 3);
```

The other issue is getting `childCount` property on a `nsINavHistoryResultNode` object - there is no such property. Before you can access properties of `nsINavHistoryContainerResultNode` you need to call `QueryInterface`, either explicitly or implicitly (via `instanceof`). So I would write:

```
} else if (node.type == 6 && node instanceof Components.interfaces.nsINavHistoryContainerResultNode) {
    var oldOpen = node.containerOpen;
    node.containerOpen = true;
    browse_bookmark_node(node, array);
    node.containerOpen = oldOpen;
}
```

Comment: @Wladimir Palant Thanks for your answer but I only need to browse bookmarksMenuFolder and the problem is really the exploration of the folders (I've updated my post to put my actual code).

Comment: @Wladimir Palant I've updated my post (I had put an older version previously, my mistake).

Comment: I updated my answer and added the other issue with your code.

Comment: @Wladimir Palant Thanks, your code works fine except when I have a folder (containing links) inside another folder. In this case the links of the folder don't appear and the folder is considered as a link.

Comment: I don't see any problems here. A nested folder still has type 6, getting its children is possible as usually.

Comment: @Wladimir Palant I don't understand why it doesn't work too. I'm going to investigate this :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just to save time to anyone who want to get all the bookmarks, do not do 
`query.setFolders([
    bookmarksService.bookmarksMenuFolder,
    bookmarksService.toolbarFolder,
    bookmarksService.unfiledBookmarksFolder
], 3);`

as suggested by Wladimir since it WON'T bring you all of the bookmarks but instead do an intersect of the folders and only give u the bookmarks which are placed at all of those folders, as written at Mozilla doc's

> You can set multiple folders and the result will be the intersection of all the folders.

( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Querying_Places )