# Get Firefox bookmarks nodes URL

Tags: javascript, firefox, url, bookmarks

What is the attribute of the nodes in Firefox Bookmarks that contains their URL ?

(I've tried node.baseURI with no success)

Comment: Which "nodes" are we talking about here?

Comment: @Pointy I'm exploring Firefox bookmarks. The type of the nodes is 0 ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262804/firefox-bookmarks-exploration-not-going-past-first-level-with-javascript )

Comment: OK.  Probably very few readers would have guessed that :-)

Comment: Maybe you could write a diagnostic routine to dump out all the properties on one of the nodes.

Comment: @Pointy Done with the attribute attributes but a For loop with node.attributes gives no output.

Comment: Well what about just a "for ... in" loop over the node?

Comment: @Pointy For attribute in node or For attribute in node.attributes gives no ouptut.

Comment: Huh.  Well, I clearly have nothing more to contribute here :-)  Maybe something at the [MDC website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/addons) will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Nodes don't have URLs as such.

An HTMLElementNode might have an id that could be used as the fragment identifier in a URL (or as a relative URL).

An HTMLElementNode might have an attribute, the value of which is a URL.

Comment: @Quentin So when I'm exploring Firefox bookmarks I can have their name but not their URL ?

Comment: Firefox bookmarks? You said nothing about those in your question. The bookmarks.html file is just HTML with wibbly bits. You can get the href attributes of the a elements.

Comment: I think that @Quentin assumed you were talking about nodes in a DOM constructed for an HTML page.

Comment: Any DOM. HTML is just the most common, so I used it for the examples. That *is* the kind of DOM you would get from a Firefox bookmarks.html file though.

Comment: @Pointy You're right : my question wasn't very clear, hence my edit :-)

Comment: @Quentin I'm not really familiar with the innards of Firefox plugins, but it seems that the browser may expose a similar, but different, structure ...

Comment: @Pointy — Ah, I hadn't twigged that this was from a plugin and not directly operating on the file.